# Convert YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS to Days

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date

I've extracted data from a power grid website and the time stamp corresponding to each power value is in the format **YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS** on Excel. I need to convert this to days but am struggling. The starting point is `2016-01-01 00:00:01` where `2016-01-01 00:00:00` will be 0 days and 2016-01-31 23:55:02 is the final time which will be 30.9965 Days.
I could do this manually but there's roughly 10,000 of these so I will need to use an equation.

[image: sample of spreadsheet]

Anyone know how to convert to days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(2016,1,31)+TIME(23,55,2)-A1
```

and apply a reasonable format to **B1**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

The cell B3 and the others with the calc in are formatted as a number to 4 decimal places.

Comment: Your approach is right, but you misread the question. The reference point is 2016-01-01 00:00:00. The first time to compare falls one second later (that's the one you're using here as a reference point). Also, if you want times as short as 1 second to show up in the result, you probably want to display 5 or 6 decimal places. If you correct your answer, flag me in a comment and I'll upvote.